# Is it proper to add structured data to a product in a store *and* on the product help page?

Tags: google-search, google

I'm adding JSON-LD markup to some software products I have created in the store I'm using to distribute them, following the [structured data guidelines from Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data).  But I also have separate help pages on another site for these software products.  Should I add the structured data there as well?

Comment: You shouldn't add structured data without knowing who is going to consume it and what benefit you get from it.   If you have to ask if you should use structured data, the answer is "no".  You tagged this as [tag:google-search] which indicates that you are hoping that Google does something with this data.   Google has  a list of the ways that they change the search results based on structured data here: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/search-gallery  If it isn't in that list, there is no benefit of adding it for Google.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to add it twice? Product structured data on product page is absolutely enough.

Beside of this help page is not a product page, so it would be only possible to use another kind of main type, like Webpage.

Sure you will be able to tie both page through something like `mainContenOfPage or`about` or similar. But i don't see very much sense in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having the same product on multiple websites. Then you do have to create the structured data for all of the products onto those different websites.

Just follow the pattern available in the google guidelines and implement the same on all the product pages available.